# How to show a default value when a grid column value is null?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I define my column grid this way:

```
grid.addColumn(u -> u.getUsername()).setCaption("User");
grid.addColumn(u -> u.getUserFullname()).setCaption("Full Name");
grid.addColumn(u -> u.getLastLoggedInDate()).setCaption("Last login");
grid.addColumn(u -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(u.getBlocked()) ? 
    "YES" : "NO").setCaption("Blocked?");
```

The column **Last login** `--> u.getLastLoggedInDate()` have a null value. Will have value later.

How can I define a default text to show ***"Not logged yet"*** before having a value

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the TextRenderer

```
grid.addColumn(u -> u.getLastLoggedInDate(), new TextRenderer("Not logged yet")).setCaption("Last login");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your lambda `u -> u.getLastLoggedInDate()` can be modified like

```
u -> u.getLastLoggedInDate() == null ? 
  "Not logged in yet" : 
  u.getLastLoggedInDate()
```

Comment: how do this with the API?